# bash if statement command not found

Tags: bash, syntax

I have the simplest issue, but I can't get this to work, and it's driving me crazy.  So I am running a script called execute.sh that has a help function.  I swear my syntax is correct below; I have tried just one equal sign and now trying two.  I have tried the double brackets and continue to get the error "[-h: command not found" .  To execute the script I run the following the command.

> sh execute.sh -h

Where -h is the argument I am passing int that forces the bash script to call the help function and then exist.  But it keeps erroring on the **IF Statement**. Not sure what else to do, any suggestions?

```
arg=$1

if ["$arg" == "-h"]; then
    helpFunction
    exit1;
fi
```

Comment: Additionally, it has to be `exit 1`, not `exit1`. https://www.shellcheck.net/ can point out things like that for you.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
["$arg" == "-h"]
```

line, you should separate the `[` from `"` also `"` from the `]` with a space. Because `[` is actually a command, so it should have a space after it, and the syntax of `[` command arguments require a space before `]`.

```
arg=$1

if [ "$arg" == "-h" ]; then
    helpFunction
    exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: You're so awesome!!  Man, that was driving me crazy.